# Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I am getting this error even though after much debugging, the array seems to be a 2D array:

```
    reg = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
    X = []
    Y = []
    with open('data/legitimate.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line in f:
            X.append(get_heuristics(line))
            Y.append(0)

    with open('data/bad.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
        for line in f:
            X.append(get_heuristics(line))
            Y.append(1)

    X = np.array(X)
    Y = np.array(Y)
    reg.fit(X, Y)
```

Where `get_heuristics()` returns a 1D array. Any reason why this could be happening? Thanks

Comment: Are the arrays `get_heuristics` returns different in size? Numpy can only process arrays where the sublists have the same size. In the other case, it will generate a 1d array of references to arrays, but that is *not* the same. (In C#, that would be the difference between `float[][]`, and `float[,]`).,

Comment: You haven't listed the error, stack trace, or line numbers, nor have you included the code for 'get_heuristics()'

Comment: Show the `shape` and `dtype` for `X`.   Maybe even part of the array.  A nice thing about Python is that you can run code interactively, and display values are various steps along the way.

Comment: @hpaulj `X.shape` returns `(4000,5)` and `Y.shape` returns `(4000,)`

Comment: this is the output of X https://imgur.com/a/ar3Yu and this is the output of Y https://imgur.com/a/Hi2Ff

Comment: So `X` is 2d and `Y` is 1d.  What's unexpected about that?

Answer (score 0):

The `X` array is a 2D array. As you correctly say `getheuristics()` returns a 1D array and appending a 1D array will make a 2D array. However the error "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" will be displayed because `Y` is only 1D. After all, you are simply appending a single digit each time, hence a 1D array. Scikit-learn's [`fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) requires two 2D arrays. As I'm sure the console will have suggested, you might want to try:

Y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)

before you call `reg.fit(X,Y)`.